# How to replace some successive blank into a tab

Tags: sed

`df -h` will give a result like following

[image]

I try to replace all successive blank into a tab in every line.So I run such command

`df -h|sed 's/ +/\t/g'`

But I don't know why it doesn't work..

Comment: You have to escape the `+` too (unless you use `sed -E`)

Comment: try simply `....| column -t`

Comment: @don_crissti But why I will get two successive tab charcaters?

Comment: @val0x00ff That work for you?

Comment: @yode try also the `... | od -a`  with sed to see literal `ht (Horizontal Tabs)`

Comment: @don_crissti I don't know why,if I run that command in my ssh terminal,The first row will have two successive tab charcaters.But if I'm in the console terminal the result will meet expectation..

Comment: @val0x00ff It will be [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/hIB7k.png)...

Comment: @don_crissti Yes,I want to use the `grep` and `cut` to extract that value of `sda5` in column `Use%` .

Comment: @yode here are a few examples : http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/094?highlight=%28df%29   scroll down at the bottom of the page

Comment: Dude, you _don't need to use `sed` then `grep` and `cut`_ you can simply run `df -h /dev/sda5 | awk 'NR>1{print $5}'` not to mention that if you're using a recent `coreutils` you can even print only the column that you want (read the manual)

Comment: @don_crissti Thanks very much.But what meaning of "recent"?

Comment: Recent like in "not very old" ([released in 2014 or later](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=799e10f3619ea7949a4f606b2f29b662daf31e3c)) ... if yours doesn't have the `--output` option then it's not "recent"

Comment: @don_crissti If as you can see,the regular expression [method](http://i.stack.imgur.com/dMWqo.png) will result two successive tab charcaters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to convert all successive spaces into a tab, you could use the following. (I'm on Ubuntu using sed version `4.2.1-9`)

Command:
`$ df -h | tr -s " " | sed 's/\s/\t/g'`

Output:

```
Filesystem  Size    Used    Avail   Use%    Mounted on
/dev/xvda1  9.8G    4.5G    5.2G    46% /
udev    3.7G    12K 3.7G    1%  /dev
tmpfs   748M    360K    748M    1%  /run
none    5.0M    0   5.0M    0%  /run/lock
none    3.7G    0   3.7G    0%  /run/shm
```

- `tr -s " "` will first squeeze all spaces into a single space.
- `sed 's/\s/\t/g` replaces all the single spaces with a tab.